# How check if find_element_by_ failed in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I have a doubt when I'am using the **find_element_by_name**, **find_element_by_id**, and similar.
For example, in this code:

```
self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("admin")
self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("admintest")
```

How should I check if some error happened? I know that I can do this:

```
try:
    self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("username").send_keys("admin")
except:
    print("OK, some problem happened to find username...")
    sys.exit(1)

try:
    self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("password").send_keys("admintest")
except:
    print("OK, some problem happened to find password...")
    sys.exit(1)
```

But if I do this I will have a lot of source code. So have someone a other solution to check the return?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't have to do anything, if error will happen, you will be notified and program will be stopped

Comment: ok, I understand you. But I would like to know if who program with Selenium use a specific manner to errors treatment, I'm starting at Selenium WebDriver and I have yet doubts with good programming practice with selenium. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Good programming practice is code like you have above, without `try/exept`

Comment: So, I will use without try/except. I made some tests here and the log output using htmlTestRunner is good (the exception reason is printed too).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, in test code you shouldn't handle any exceptions the script throws because your script is *meant* to be failed when an exception is raised which is exactly what you normally should want from your script.

For example, if you write something like -

```
self.elem = self.driver.find_element_by_name("some_name")
```

Now, if your HTML page under test doesn't contains any such element, your script *should* fail to indicate such an occurence displaying any exception which was thrown.

You may want to handle any exceptions in your test script only in specific scenarios like -

1) You want to find same element with some other locator (not a good practice though).

2) You need to wait for some time and try again finding the same element (not a good practice again, you should use [waits](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) instead).

3) You don't want your script to fail immediately when a single element is not located. May be you want your individual script to *atleast* continue finding other elements and perform other assertions so that you have an overall idea of what is the current status of your web application is.

4) You want to display the raised exception in a user friendly way(just like you did) along with the stack trace.

5) You want a failure count for your tests running in a suite (normally not required because your runner should give you a build summary).

So, overall there is not really a solid good reason to handle any exceptions in your script because your test scripts *should* ideally run without any of them. Handling them will make your runner not recognise it as a failed test and it won't serve the purpose of writing scripts.

Comment: For example:

    try:
         alert = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 5).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
                (By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".alert.alert-warning>strong")))
    except:
        raise ValueError("Error: Cannot find the Alert-warning")

I have **alert-warnings** and **alert-success**, in this situation it's happen a firmware upgrade, then I need to wait a little time to continue, so is there other way to test this (without WebDriverWait)? Because the waits doesn't stop the tests if alert isn't show and it's necessary the try/except to stop.

Comment: Waits will stop the execution by throwing a timeout exception. Just don't handle it by except and your execution will be stopped.

Comment: Remember if you are using try except, you are telling the program to NOT stop. So if you want your script to stop, just don't use try except.